# React Hook - Cannot Call Parent Component Dispatch in Child Component onComplete Callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I've tried several solutions to fix this problem, and none have worked.

I have a third-party library that calls an asynchronous function to load something to render in the DOM.

I have a component that wraps the library for the DOM piece and when it finishes I want to be able to call an `onComplete` method with it.

Everything works fine. However when I call the `onComplete` function, and then inside that function is a call to `dispatch` something to a `context` it blows up and gives me the

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

## Code

```
export function ParentComponent(props: any) {
    const dispatch: any = React.useContext(dispatchContext);
    const onComplete = React.useCallback(
        (data: any) => {
            if (dispatch !== null && dispatch !== undefined) {
                dispatch({
                    payload: { new_data: "thing" },
                    type: dispatchType.UPDATING
                });
            }
        },
        [dispatch]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent onComplete={onComplete} />
        </div>
    );
}
interface IProp {
    onComplete?: function;
}
export function ChildComponent(props: IProp) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (library.is_ready) {
            library.load(data).then(
                () => {
                    console.log("Success");
                    props.onComplete(library);
                },
                (error: any) => {
                    console.error("ERROR");
                }
            );
        }
    }, [library]);

    return <div id="library-dom-element"></div>;
}
```

If I comment out the `dispatch` function this won't blow up.

It blows up when the asynchronous function is completed and calls the `onComplete` function which calls the `dispatch`

`ChildComponent.libary.is_ready` → `ChildComponent.libary.load` → `ChildComponent.libary.onComplete` → `ParentComponent.onComplete` → `dispatch`

I have tried adding `useCallback` to everything. I have tried using `useRef` to track an `is_mounted` variable to determine if the DOM pieces are loading correctly.

I just cannot figure out how to call `dispatch` on the completion of the third party library.

That's literally it.

Can anyone help or provide guidance on this? I thought I understood how these pieces work together, but I'm missing something.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the error using the code you provided? Would you not get a type error saying "dispatch is not a function"?

Comment: No it's not possible in its current form. This is a rough sketch of the code being used.

The `dispatch` part is another component that was created with `React.createContext` and `React.useReducer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application I've been making has been pretty complex.

The bug I provided here is a result of component initialization order that arises because of how I am toggling state.

When I created a delay function to help buffer initialization this resolved the issue for the time being.

Apologies for this question as the design pattern does appear to work, there just needs to be accounting for how your React application's complexity is being managed.

Thank you to everyone who took a look :) <3